# SQL Query - Returning results for specific item parameters error on conversion

Tags: sql

I have created the query below and i am receiving the following error:

Query I am using:

```
        IF(SELECT CAST(OITM.ITEMCODE as int) FROM OITM 
        WHERE
        OITM.SELLITEM = 'Y' AND 
        OITM.PrchseItem ='N' AND 
        OITM.ITEMCODE <> 'Avatax' AND 
        OITM.ITEMCODE <> '5564006' AND 
        OITM.ITEMCODE <> '5564005' 
        AND OITM.InvntItem = 'N' 
        AND CAST(OITM.ITEMCODE as int)='3945000-55-500 R' ) > 0 

        BEGIN
        SELECT 'YES' FOR BROWSE
        END
```

Error: Conversion failed when converting the `varchar` value `3945000-55-500 R` to data type `int`.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why do you cast `OITM.ITEMCODE` to integer since you want to compare it to a varchar?

Comment: he answer is quite simple: you are trying to convert a string into an integer, where the string value is not possible to convert. What integer value do you expect from '3945000-55-500 R'

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product and there is no `IF` in standard SQL. Please [add a tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: What, specifically, are you trying to compare the "cast" value to, where (in your code) it is greater than zero?  Do you just want the numeric portion of the string?  is it supposed to be a calculation like "3945000 minus 55 minus 500 is greater than 0"?

Comment: The rules for [data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) require that a comparison of an `int` to a string must first convert the string to an `int`. As has been suggested, `'3945000-55-500 R'` is not an integer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the data in OITM.ITEMCODE not an integer 
you can't casting OITM.ITEMCODE because it have a value = "3945000-55-500 R" and this value containe some char like '-' , 'R' , and white space between 0 and r 
and we use cast or convert when we have
a variable varchar containe number "just number " like : '123' or '1457' not '125R'